# Flash Player crashes in any Firefox-Flash Player-Combination

Tags: windows-8, firefox, flash, flash-player

I´m trying to fix a problem with the flash player. I installed following Versions in combination with each another:

```
Firefox 19.0
Firefox 20.0
Firefox 21.0 (beta)
Firefox 23.0 (nightly)
```

with flash players:

```
FLP 11.7.700.169
FLP 11.6.602.180
FLP 11.6.602.167
FLP 11.6.602.168
```

When I go to Youtube and start any video the flash player crashes.

I tried it with Internet Explorer 10 and it worked. (IE 10 has a built in FLP Version)

My Operating System is Windows 8 x64 OEM on a Preinstalled ASUS Notebook.

Any tips(Except reinstalling Windows 8 (It´s not possible) or switching to another browser)?

**EDIT:**
The Flash player crashes on every pge with flashcontent.
The HTML5-Version of Youtube does contain only a few videos.
It´s maybe not possible to disable the Protected Mode

Comment: Why is it not possible to reinstall Windows?  You might have to accept that is the only solution.

Comment: Why use a beta version of Firefox? I suggest to uninstall Flash and FF, delete folders, and install a stable version.

Comment: Have you installed any kind of Adblocker ? or Firewall/Antivirus ? or something like peerblock ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uninstall](http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/support/uninstall_flash_player.exe) Flash Player

Install [Flash Player 10.3](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/win/install_flash_player_10_plugin.exe)

Reference: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/adobe-flash-plugin-has-crashed

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling protected mode in flash: http://techdows.com/2012/06/disable-flash-players-protected-mode-for-firefox.html

Make sure to install all windows updates, as microsoft released several fixes for flash.

Lastly, if this only happens on youtube, you can switch your youtube to HTML5 player if you like: http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: First of all, the Flash Player crashes on every page with flashcontent. The HTML5-Solution is well thought, but not every video is available in HTML5. And last but not least: in the versions I use there is no mms.cfg file, which is necessary to disable protected Mode.

Comment: If the mms.cfg file does not exist, create one using any standard text editor (e.g.. notepad) http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1018071?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a pristine Firefox profile? Start Firefox with "-ProfileManager" and create a new profile.

Then try to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ and see if the flash intro loads, then try those other sites.

If Firefox crashes, Windows should report the crash (if it does not: enable "error reporting" in system preferences → system → advanced) - from there you could click "Details" and see (and post) the actual crash, maybe we can see from the backtrace *why* it crashes.